# link_to not working and getting Page not found Only get and post requests are allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
My route.rb:
------------

  *resources :accounts, :path => "expos" do
    resources :shows, :path => "events" do
    resources :show_sessions, :path => "session"
    end
end*

<% @events.each do |e| %>
<%= link_to '<i class=icon-trash></i>'.html_safe, account_show_path(@context.id, e), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <% end %>
```

Rake Routes:

```
    account_shows GET    /expos/:account_id/events(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"shows"}
                  POST   /expos/:account_id/events(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"shows"}
 new_account_show GET    /expos/:account_id/events/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"shows"}
edit_account_show GET    /expos/:account_id/events/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"shows"}
     account_show GET    /expos/:account_id/events/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shows"}
                  PUT    /expos/:account_id/events/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"shows"}
                  DELETE /expos/:account_id/events/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"shows"}
```

I have delete route. But i am getting "Only get and post requests are allowed". Please help anybody why i am getting error.

Comment: Can you post your application.js file code? It should be here: `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: Made an edit for you that works for me just fine!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing it to this;

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
      <%= link_to '<i class=icon-trash></i>'.html_safe, account_show_path(@context, @event), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Make sure you have the following in your header;

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: i was tried account_show_path(@context) also that not working. Because the account_show_path(@context,e) requires two arguments. But still i am getting **Only get and post requests are allowed**. Can anybody solve this issue.